# How do I put logical operators in an Excel =IF Formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function

I'm trying to enter a formula to display text according to an IF condition. The best I can manage is something like...

```
=IF(myval>=minval & myval <= maxval, "OK", "Not OK")
```

But this appears to work exactly wrongly, displaying OK when myval is out of range and Not OK when it is in range. How do I specify the logical AND correctly? I have tried && as I have seen in questions here, and inner brackets, but these result in errors.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The logical operations are represented by formulae:

```
 AND( condition1 , condition2 , ... )

 OR( condition1 , condition2 , ... )

 NOT( condition )
```

Each condition can be pretty much anything with a logical evaluation, meaning you can nest logical operations by nesting the formulae as required.

So in your case you need:

```
 =IF( AND( myval>=minval , myval <= maxval ), "OK", "Not OK")
```